# MissingPluginException in the Huawei Site kit in flutter

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

Trying to integrate the Huawei Site kit in the Flutter but getting the below error.

4508-4583/com.learn.flashscreen E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method textSearch on channel com.huawei.hms.flutter.site/method)

Comment: Kill your application completely and reinstall it from scratch. Usually adding a new plugin and hot reloading gives this problem.

Comment: **No implementation found for method textSearch on channel com.huawei.hms.flutter.site/method** Either the plugin version or the plugin installation is incorrect. Plz check these two parts first :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Please update the [Flutter Site Plugin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Library/flutter-sdk-download-0000001050434643) to the latest version.
2. Either of the following ways can be used to integrate packages. Please check the your integration steps according to the docs [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/integrate-plugin-0000001050421239#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050421239__section11766135317266).

- Run the following command from a console window that has the Flutter directory in the path.

```
[project_path]> flutter pub get
```

- Click the corresponding button in your editor.

In Android Studio or IntelliJ, click **Packages get** in the action ribbon at the top of the **pubspec.yaml** file.

In VS Code, click **Get Packages** on the right of the action ribbon at the top of **pubspec.yaml** file.